# CSS in Rails background-color not working in body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my application.css my I have this style:

```
body {
    /*background-image: url(back.jpg);*/
    background-color: #343434;
}
```

If I uncomment the background-image property, it works just fine but I don't want the image anymore and I want the solid color. However, the background color is not showing up.

I am using Rails 4 with Bootstrap 3 and Sass (though this file is not scss)

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

Don't know about `bootstrap` specifically, but this may help resolve the problem:

```
html, body { background: #343434; }
```

This will give the whole document (`html`) a background of `#343434`, which will override any of the potential presets from bootstrap

---

**Precompile**

As mentioned by Mike Riley, you may also have an [assets precompile](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) issue:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This wouldn't be a problem in development (just production)

Comment: You're right the problem was the html tag. Once I added ```html body {}``` it worked

Answer (score 1):

Are you using asset pipeline with Rails by chance?  If so run:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

That will clear out any changes and it should show up.  If you are not using asset pipeline or that doesn't work.  Try inspecting the css style in the browser.  Just to see if you can find anything on the page.  Let me know if any of this helps.

Mike Riley

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to separate the URL with a comma.

```
background-image: url('back.jpg');
```

You can see the w3school about the syntax of background-image.
[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: OP said he doesn't want image

Comment: oops, sorry for misunderstanding.